# How do I achieve negative padding in CSS?

Tags: html, css, fonts, css-position, padding

I am looking for a way to effectively achieve negative padding in CSS.

### The Problem

I have an `h1` element on my web page that currently has the following code associated with it:

```css
h1 {
  background-color: #375E97;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 49px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous|Roboto:400,700,400i" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Lorem Ipsun Al</h1>
</body>
```

You can see that since I have added: `height: 49px;`, the text looks as if it is flowing into the rest of the page. I want to achieve this look, but also for the top of the text, not just the bottom.

### What I Have Tried

I have tried:

- Setting both `padding` and `margin` to `0` for the `h1` element.
- Playing with various values for `vertical-align`.
- Setting `height` to many different values.
- Setting all the `h1`'s parent elements' `padding` and `margin` to `0`.

**I believe that the problem I am facing is that the top of the font I am using (and most fonts) has some space. This is why I want to be able to achieve a negative padding, to move the text up on the screen without moving the content box.**

Comment: There cannot be anything such as negative padding. If there was, then it wouldn't be padding at all.

Comment: I know this is not the answer to the main question, but for anyone else who might be here because of the same reason as mine, notice the <br>s in the html document too!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It completly depends on the font you use, but in your particular case  `height: 34px`and `line-height: 34px;` do what you want:

```css
h1 {
  background-color: #375E97;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 34px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous|Roboto:400,700,400i" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Lorem Ipsun Al</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a negative margin on the inner content to achieve the same thing as negative padding would.

Comment: Somehow I had to combine this with a negative `vertical-align`.

Answer (score 2):

The one thing you didn't try is adjusting the `line-height`.

> [**10.8 Line height calculations: the `line-height` and `vertical-align`
>   properties**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#line-height)
>
> On a block container element whose content is composed of inline-level
>   elements, `line-height` specifies the minimal height of line boxes
>   within the element.

```css
h1 {
    background-color: #375E97;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: .6;
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem Ipsun Al</h1>
```